# Laravel 5.0 Many To Many Query With Where clause

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need some help with laravel 5.0. 
I have these three table's
Company-> Has Many Categories
Category-> Has Many Companies
In database i have pivot talbe Company_Categories.
My question is this: How to get all companies where category is == 1.

```
public static function LoadCompaniesBySearch($catId, $conId, $firstLetter){

    $suppliersViewModel = Company::whereHas('category',function($q)
    {
        $q->where('category_id',$catId);
    })->all();

    foreach($suppliersViewModel as $model)
    {
        echo $model->name .'<br/>';
    }
}
```

I've tried with this but i get following error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::category()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$suppliersViewModel = Company::whereHas('category',function($q) use($catId)
    {
        $q->where('category_id',$catId);
    })->all();
```